# Access JSON object in java

Tags: java, json

I need to update a value in my JSON file using java but somehow I am unable to.Following is my JSON format which I am trying to parse

```
{
  "recentActivities":[  
     { 
       "displayValue":"POC | Augmented Reality", 
       "link":"poc.jsp?search=augmented%20reality",
       "timestamp":"18/07/2013 17:33"
     },
     { 
       "displayValue":"POC | Image Editing in Hybrid Application", 
       "link":"poc.jsp?search=image%20editing",
       "timestamp":"18/07/2013 01:00"
     }
   ],

  "lastEmailSent": "29/06/2013 00:00"
}
```

I need to update `lastEmailSent` to current date but somehow I am getting stuck. Below is my java code which i am using

```
private void updateLastEmailTimeStamp(String jsonFilePath) {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject lastEmailTimeStamp = new JSONObject();

    FileReader reader =null;
    try {
        File jsonFile = new File(jsonFilePath);
        reader = new FileReader(jsonFile);
        jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);

        lastEmailTimeStamp = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("lastEmailSent");

        //write current date as last mail sent time.
        writeTimeStamp(lastEmailTimeStamp, jsonFile);

        APP_LOGGER.info("last Email Sent timestamp updated");       
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        APP_LOGGER.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        APP_LOGGER.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
    } 

}


private void writeTimeStamp(JSONObject lastEmailTimeStamp, File jsonFile) {
    FileWriter writer = null;
    try{
         writer = new FileWriter(jsonFile);

         String currentDate = MyDateFormatterUtility.formatDate(new Date(),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

         lastEmailTimeStamp.put(SubscriptionConstants.LAST_EMAIL_TIMESTAMP, currentDate);

         writer.write(lastEmailTimeStamp.toJSONString());
      }catch(IOException ex){
          APP_LOGGER.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
      }finally{
             try {
             writer.flush();
             writer.close();
             } catch (IOException ex) {
             APP_LOGGER.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
             }
      }
}
```

I am getting error in the following line

`lastEmailTimeStamp = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("lastEmailSent");`.

I guess I am not correctly parsing or accessing the object. Can somebody please make me correct? 
Thank you!

Comment: I am unable to track the error actually. The debugger after that line goes to some thread class and just stops.

Comment: I'm assuming your method is throwing a `RuntimeException`, so add an additional `catch (Exception ex)` to your try-catch to find out what it is

Comment: Not your problem, but you shouldn't be initializing jsonObject and lastEmailTimestamp, since those values just get overwritten.

Comment: And what is the error?  If it's a ClassCastException that's probably because you're trying to cast a String to a JSONObject.

Comment: Declare lastEmailTimestamp to be an Object, cast the output of jsonObject.get to Object, and dump the class of the result.  (Or cut out the middleman and just declare it to be a String and cast to String.)

Comment: Yeah. So how would i now change my `writeTimeStamp` method to incorporate the changes?

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out what writeTimeStamp is supposed to be doing.  It's certainly not updating the original JSON, since jsonObject is not passed to it.

Comment: Hehe. Yeah Silly mistakes. Thanks for the help @Hot Licks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i was able to figure out the solution. Following changes were needed in the code

```
private void updateLastEmailTimeStamp(String jsonFilePath) {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    FileReader reader =null;
    try {
        File jsonFile = new File(jsonFilePath);
        reader = new FileReader(jsonFile);
        jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);

        jsonObject.remove("lastEmailSent");


        //write current date as last mail sent time.
        writeTimeStamp(jsonObject, jsonFile);

        APP_LOGGER.info("last Email Sent timestamp updated");       
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        APP_LOGGER.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        APP_LOGGER.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


/**
 * Method to write current date as last mail sent timestamp 
 * denoting when the newsletter was sent last.
 * 
 * @param jsonObj- date for last email sent.
 * @param jsonFile - recentactivities.json file
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void writeTimeStamp(JSONObject jsonObj, File jsonFile) {
    FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(jsonFile);

        String currentDate = MyDateFormatter.formatDate(new Date(),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

        jsonObj.put("lastEmailSent", currentDate);


        writer.write(jsonObj.toJSONString());
    }catch(IOException ex){
        APP_LOGGER.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
    }finally{
        try {
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            APP_LOGGER.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Hot Licks, but you can try fixing it by doing:

```
String lastEmailSent = jsonObject.getString("lastEmailSent");
```

Also, if that isn't the problem, it may be that the text coming from your file is not exactly the JSON text you posted here.  In which case, you can read the file into a string, add a breakpoint and check the string to see if it has all the JSON elements you expect it to.

In Java 7 you can read the text in like:

```
String content = readFile(jsonFilePath, Charset.defaultCharset());

static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
    throws IOException 
{
      byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
      return encoding.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(encoded)).toString();
}
```

Comment: Even after making the object string, I am not able to successfully overwrite the json object value

Comment: Ok, sorry.  It was not at all clear from your question that you were having trouble other than the casting error.  I'm glad you figured it out.